# How do I count the number of dates within a dataset according to a class

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am trying to make another dataframe where it counts the total amount of times a date appears in my input csv file

example input:
date / class_id / count
2021-09-01 / A / 1
2021-09-01 / A / 2
2021-09-01 / A / 3
2021-09-01 / B / 1
2021-09-02 / A / 1
2021-09-02 / C / 1
2021-09-02 / C / 2

expected output:
date / class_id / count
2021-09-01 / A / 3
2021-09-01 / B / 1
2021-09-02 / A / 1
2021-09-02 / C / 2

this is my code so far!

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive', force_remount = True)

import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_csv('gdrive/My Drive/Colab_Notebooks/classproject/classdata.csv', parse_dates=['timedate'], index_col='timedate')
class_id = data['class_id']
data['date'] = data.index.date

class_id = data['class_id']
timedate = data.index.to_series()
m1 = class_id.ne(class_id.shift())
m2 = timedate.dt.date.ne(timedate.dt.date.shift())
data['count'] = data.groupby((m1 | m2).cumsum()).cumcount().add(1).values
```

Comment: `df[['date', 'class_id']].value_counts(sort=False).reset_index()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Code**

use `groupby` + `max`

```
out = df.groupby(['date', 'class_id'])['count'].max().reset_index()
```

out:

```
         date class_id  count
0  2021-09-01        A      3
1  2021-09-01        B      1
2  2021-09-02        A      1
3  2021-09-02        C      2
```

Or `groupby` + `size` or `count`

```
out = df.groupby(['date', 'class_id'])['count'].size().reset_index()
out = df.groupby(['date', 'class_id'])['count'].count().reset_index()
```

---

**Example Code**

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'date': ['2021-09-01', '2021-09-01', '2021-09-01', '2021-09-01', '2021-09-02', '2021-09-02', '2021-09-02'], 
         'class_id': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'C'], 
         'count': [1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
```